# How to enable multicore processing with sklearn LDA?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, scikit-learn, multicore, lda

I have a topics model using `sklearn LDA`. My corpus have **~75K** documents and matrix shape generate from corpus is `X.shape = (74645, 91542)`

When I pass this matrix to `sklearn LDA` it takes 3 hrs on my local and on server it is using **11 hrs**.

So my question is:

## Is there a way to use multicore processing in sklearn LDA? or is there a way to reduce my processing time significantly?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Please take a look at the code:

line that generated lda_output takes hours to run

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english', ngram_range= (1,2), vocabulary = word_list)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

lda_model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=50,            # Number of topics
                                      learning_decay=0.7,
                                      max_iter=10,               # Max learning iterations
                                      learning_method='online',
                                      random_state=100,          # Random state
                                      batch_size=128,            # n docs in each learning iter
                                      evaluate_every = -1,       # compute perplexity every n iters, default: Don't
                                      n_jobs = -1,               # Use all available CPUs
                                     )

#--Because before this line system was running out of memory

%env JOBLIB_TEMP_FOLDER=/tmp

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

lda_output = lda_model.fit_transform(X)

end_time = datetime.datetime.now()

run_time_lda = end_time - start_time

#output:
#datetime.timedelta(0, 38157, 730304) ~ 11hrs
```

Comment: With `n_jobs=-1` you're already multiprocessing. You may further reduce processing times by (i) downcasting your data to `np.float32` or (ii) using `gensim`'s `word2vec` word embeddings. In the latter case the feature's dimensionality may be reduced by couple of orders.

Comment: I don't know what happens under the hood in scikit, but when I tried using it on a small dataset it loaded all my cores for an hour, while gensim did it in like 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to rethink about your vocabulary `word_list`, which seems to be bigger than your documents count.  Try building the vocabulary from the documents itself, if it can work in your problem.

Also specify the `min_df` to remove the very low frequency words. May be lemmatization/ stemming could be of use to reduce the vocabulary size and it would also helps the lda to learn better topics.

I would recommend not to use bigrams/trigrams for lda modelling, because it might lead to uninterpretable model.

Comment: I am glad that it helped! Kindly go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers